# hide or show div depending on two checkboxes (at least one is checked)

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I'm trying to show or hide a button when at least one of two checkboxes is checked, I'm trying with jQuery but it doesn't work.
Can anyone help me, or show some example that I can use?

Here's my code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="p1_perro" class="checks" name="p1[]" value="p1_perro" />
<label>Perro</label><br /> 

<input type="checkbox" id="p1_gato" class="checks" name="p1[]" value="p1_gato" />
<label>Gato</label><br />     

<input type="checkbox" id="p1_pajaro" name="p1[]" value="p1_pajaro" />
<label>Pájaro</label><br />

<input type="checkbox" id="p1_roedor" name="p1[]" value="p1_roedor" />
<label>Roedor</label><br />
```

```js
if ($('.checks').find('input:checked').length < 0) {
    $("#btnSiguiente1").hide();
    $("#enviar").show();
}
else {
    $("#btnSiguiente1").show();
    $("#enviar").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not use .find(), it looks for descendant elements

```
if($('.checks:checked').length == 0){
  $("#btnSiguiente1").hide();
  $("#enviar").show();
}else{
  $("#btnSiguiente1").show();
  $("#enviar").hide();
}
```

or use filter

```
if($('.checks').filter('input:checked').length == 0){
  $("#btnSiguiente1").hide();
  $("#enviar").show();
}else{
  $("#btnSiguiente1").show();
  $("#enviar").hide();
}
```

Note: This has to be executed in the change handler for `.checks` like

```
var $checks = $('.checks').change(function () {
    var flag = $checks.filter(':checked').length == 0;
    $("#btnSiguiente1").toggle(!flag);
    $("#enviar").toggle(flag);
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qnGLL/)

Comment: @xpy yes hopefully OP has handled that case

Answer (score 1):

The number of checked items can never be less than zero, so your `if` statement logic is flawed in that regard. Also, the selector is looking for an `input` as a child of `.checks`, which is incorrect. Try this:

```
if ($('.checks:checked').length == 0){
    $("#btnSiguiente1").hide();
    $("#enviar").show();
}
else {
    $("#btnSiguiente1").show();
    $("#enviar").hide();
}
```

Comment: thak you very much, i had been loking and thinking how to solve this problem and in 6 minutes you gave me the solution, incredible! you are a really good team.

regards!

Comment: @pablo no problem at all. Don't forget to upvote and accept this answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/t8FsN/)</kbd>

```
var checks = $('.checks'),
    enviar = $("#enviar"),
    btnSiguiente1 = $("#btnSiguiente1");
btnSiguiente1.add(enviar).hide();
checks.change(function () {
    if (checks.filter(':checked').length) {
        btnSiguiente1.hide();
        enviar.show();
    } else {
        btnSiguiente1.show();
        enviar.hide();
    }
});
```